# Homologous curves and partitions

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is kind of a dumb question, but suppose that $\gamma \in Z_1(X)$ is a cycle. In other words its a closed curve $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow X$. Suppose we have a partition $0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n=1$. Why is the chain $\gamma_1+\cdots+\gamma_n$ homologous to $\gamma$ where $\gamma_i$ is $\gamma$ on $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ rescaled to the unit interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reduce to the case $n=2$. We have then a map $\gamma:[0,1]\to X$
and then split it into two subpaths $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$. There's
a map $\phi:\Delta_2\to[0,1]$ where $\Delta_2$ is the standard
$2$-simplex taking its vertices in order to $0$, $t_1$ and $1$. We can make
this an affine map. Then consider $\gamma\circ \phi:\Delta_2\to X$.
This is a $2$-chain in $X$. Its boundary is just the $1$-chain
$\gamma_2-\gamma+\gamma_1$. So that $1$-chain is a $1$-boundary, thus
$\gamma_1+\gamma_2$ is homologous to $\gamma$.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to explain the case $n=3$ since the generalization is more applicable for finer partitions.

Comment: Beyond this is just induction: with $n=3$, $\gamma_1+\gamma_2$ is homologous to $\gamma'$, the restriction of $\gamma$ to $[0,t_2]$ so $\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3\sim\gamma'+\gamma_3\sim\gamma$ etc.

Comment: Ahh never mind. I see. Thanks.